# How to save HTML5 canvas as a link so other people can see and share

Tags: php, html, canvas

I have an application where the user can draw pictures, this all works fine. The problem I keep on having is that I want to be able to share the user's drawing so others can also see and share. As of now I am using this code to save canvas:

```
window.location = canvas.toDataUrl();
```

But the problem with this is that the picture is only generated on the client side, which I don't want. I have no experience with php/ mysql or server side languages but however I do have experience with html, css ,javascript. Anyways... any help would be much appreciated

thanks

Comment: I think you are going to have to involve a database. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is obvious. In HTML5 canvas, what you draw from javascript is done at client side. So if you want to share the drawing what you can do is export it to a image
[This might help](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/)

Hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach if you want the users to share the image over a link to your page: save the image to a database with a unique key, which the users can use to share with other people. Now you have to provide a method which accepts the generated key, loads the image from the database and returns it to the client.
Another approach would be to give the users the possibility to download the created image e.g. as PNG, which is supported by all html5-browsers.

Comment: Yes in my application, the user has the option to download his/her artwork to the computer. What I am asking is when the user hits the save button it generates a url like this:  www.example.com/1234567
The only problem with that is, I don't think javascript allows for that to happen, and I don't have much experience with server side languages like php.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call toDataURL on the canvas and you'll get a base64 encoded image which can be passed into the browsers address bar to render the image.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var image = document.getElementById("someImage");
ctx.fillRect(100,100,100,100);
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

var link = document.getElementById("link");

link.addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), '_blank');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LvZQF/